# Hostname issues after upgrading server from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, ssh

So I recently updated my ubuntu server from 18.04 to 20.04, but now I can't seem to connect to my server via hostname. The router settings haven't changed, and im still getting the correct static IP. However when trying to connect to the server from windows via putty, I can only connect via the static IP and not the hostname. Similarly, I can't connect to the samba server hosted on the ubuntu server. One thing I did notice is that there were some cloud config changes squashed in the upgrade, and also my hostname reverted to a different hostname on reboot. I changed the hostname back after changing persist_hostname to true, and using hostnamectl, but neither hostname is usable on the LAN.

Another fun detail is that if i use nslookup on a LAN device, and search for my hostname I do get the correct static IP, which suggests that it might not DHCP since this device is somehow still getting the hostname somehow. It just can't actually connect via that name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out Windows was doing some really weird DNS resolution, where it would check for a WINS server, not find one, then not process to check DNS for some reason. This is why I could use nslookup on that machine and see the correct hostname and IP for my server on there, but when trying to ping it wouldn't work. nslookup was using the right DNS, and ping was not.

The solution was as simple as using a . after the hostname to make it fully qualified, which for some reason made windows check DNS and connect right away. Once I get it connected once, I could then disconnect and re-connect without having to add the dot, meaning I can connect like normal. I really have no idea how that happened, given the windows machine and router didn't change, only the ubuntu server. To make it even weirder, another PC I had off at the time booted up after I got it sorted and it didn't have an issue finding without fully qualification. I have no explanation for that one.